# Visual Studio 6 and Teamcity - how to set up a build configuration?

Tags: teamcity, buildconfiguration, visual-studio-6

I have to set up a build configuration (Teamcity 7.1) for some old Visual Studio 6 C projects. I am not common with C/C++ programs and their environment and have absolutely no idea how to configure the build steps for this kind of projects. I installed the cmake plugin on Teamcity server and agent and tried to set up a GNUMake configuration with pointing the "Make program path" to the nmake.exe from the Visual Studio 6 installation. The build actually starts, but crashes with the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance-Dienstprogramm: Version 6.00.9782.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1988-1998. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
NMAKE : fatal error U1065: invalid option '-'
Stop.
```

I am not passing any command line parameters in. As far as i have found out it seems to be a problem with the nmake/make combination and can be fixed with prefixing the nmake call with `env -u MAKE -u MAKEFLAGS nmake.exe /a /l`. Unfortunately that doesn't work either - or maybe i'm doing it wrong.

Does anyone have experience with Visual Studio 6 and Teamcity? Is there any advice how i can set up a proper build step?

Kind regards,
Daniela

Answer (score 1):

From what you stated, you have Visual Studio 6 installed on the build agent. Therefore I think the easiest way is to just use the TeamCity "Command Line" build step and run `msdev` to build the project.

[MSDN has documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699274%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) on the command line parameters for `msdev`, but here is an example:

```
msdev MyProject.dsp /MAKE "MyProject – Win32 Debug" /REBUILD
```